# JavaScript/HTML/Unicode accents: á != á

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

I want to check if a user submitted string is the same as the string in my answer key. Sometimes the words involve Spanish accents (like in sábado), and that makes the condition always false.

I have Firebug log `$('#answer').val()` and it shows up as `sábado`. (The `á` comes from a button that inserts the value `&aacute;`, if that matters) whereas logging the answer from the answer key shows `s&aacute;bado` (how I wrote it in the actual answer key).

I have tried replacing the `&aacute` in the answer key with a normal `á`, but it still doesn't work, and results in a Unicode diamond-question-mark. When I do that and also replace the value of the button that makes the user-submitted `á`, the condition works correctly, but then the button, the user string, and the answer string all have the weird Unicode diamond-question-mark.

I have also tried using `&#225;` in both places and it's no different from using `&aacute;`. Both my HTML and Javascript are using `charset="utf-8"`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you give some sample in jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: So it seems that in one case you're comparing `s&aacute;bado` to `sábado`, which is of course `false`. In another case you're comparing `s�bado` to `sábado`, which is also `false`. Seems like a simple encoding problem...?

Comment: What does that `.length` propery of each string return? How about `.charAt(1)`?

Comment: @Gabe: .length of the user value is 6, .length of answer key value is 13. .charAt(1) of the user value is b, .charAt(1) of the answer key value is &.

Comment: I suspect you are using HTML entities inside of JS, possibly with code that says something like `answer = "s&aacute;bado"` instead of `answer = "s\xE1bado"`.

Comment: I was! And your suggestion fixed it! If you put this as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're consistently using UTF-8, there's no need for HTML entities except to encode syntax (ie `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;` and - within attributes - `&quot;`).

For anything else, use the proper characters, and your problems should go away - until you run into unicode normalization issues, ie the difference between `'a\u0301'` and `'\u00E1'`...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're not using the real UTF-8 characters in both strings (entered answer and the key). You should NOT be supplying "a button that inserts the value á" -- Re: "if that matters" it does!

The characters should be added by the keyboard input system. And your comparison string should also be only utf-8 characters. It should NOT be character entities.

Comment: Thanks... considering that adding by button is really important to my program, is there a way to convert the character entity to UTF-8 using JavaScript? My Google skills are failing me.